# Please help me to solve the differential equation $y' = (y/2) \cos x + (1/y) \sin (2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me to solve this differential equation: $y' = \frac{y}{2}\cos (x) + \frac{1}{y}\sin (2x)$?

Comment: Grouping a little unclear.  Do you mean $y' = (y/2) * \cos x + (1/y) * \sin(2x)$?

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes that's right

Comment: Thanks for the speedy clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply both sides by $y$ we get
$$
yy'+\frac{y^2}{2}\cos x=\sin 2x
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{2} (y^2)'+\frac{y^2}{2}\cos x=\sin 2x
$$
we write $u=\frac12 y^2e^{\int^x\cos x} =\frac12 y^2e^{\sin x} $ ($e^{\int^x\cos x}$  is an integrating factor prescribed for such an equation) we get
$$
u'e^{-\sin x}=\sin2x
$$
Which is solved to give
$$
u=\int^x\sin 2x e^{\sin x}+c=2e^{\sin x}(\sin x-1)+c_1
$$
Thus
$$
y^2=4e^{-\sin x}(e^{\sin x}(\sin x-1)+c_1)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is linear in $u=y^2$. You can consider this as a case of a Bernoulli equation
$$
u'=u\cos x+2\sin(2x).
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y' = \frac{y}{2}\;\cos (x) + \frac{1}{y}\sin (2x)$$
$$\cos x \dfrac {dy}{d\sin x} = \frac{y}{2}\cos (x) + \frac{2}{y}\sin x \cos x$$
$$\dfrac {dy}{dv} = \frac{y}{2} + \frac{2v}{y}$$
$$\dfrac 12\dfrac {dy^2}{dv} = \frac{y^2}{2} +{2v}$$
$$\dfrac {du}{dv} = {u} +{4v}$$
$$u'-u=4v$$
Where $u=y^2$ and $v= \sin x$
$$(ue^{-v})'=4ve^{-v}$$
Integrate.